# Add durability to items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know if it is possible to add durability to items ?

Example :

I've 1 Prismarine Shard, and I want that to be broken after it breaks 1 block.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the player right clicking you can use the method [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228250/minecraft-item-right-left-click-detection). This will allow you execute a command when the player right clicks. In this case remove the `prismarine_shard` item from the players inventory.

With a server plugin or mod you could also do this but that would require a great deal more work. Only a mod could add durability to the item icon in the player's inventory.

Comment: Well, Forge mod to add durability would not be that hard, if there is some basic knowledge about Java and basic modding, however changes to the client/server are quite big step, that is probably bigger problem ( all clients need same setup as server etc)